# Redirect authenticated users to a particular page

Tags: 2007, authentication, redirect

I have an anonymous access publishing site that has a 'Log In' link.  I would like to redirect successfully authenticated users to a particular page.

So, a user could be looking at any page on the anonymous access public site, then they click log in, and if they authenticate correctly then they should be redirected to a specifc URL of my choosing.

Currently I am using Windows authentication, but it would be useful if it could also work for forms-based.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your signin url to include the source querystring and value to what you want they will be redirected:

For instance:

/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2Fimages%2Fblank%2Egif

that url will redirect the user to a blank image after authentication.

Comment: As a note to this answer, I was using the Welcome.ascx user control for the Sign In link, which autoredirects you to the page you were at when you clicked sign in.  I've made my own Welcome control (based on the original) to change this behaviour.